# How to get the dependency tree in a Maven 3 plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aether

In a Maven 2 mojo you can use something like this to get the dependency tree:

```
DependencyNode rootNode;
try {
  rootNode = treeBuilder.buildDependencyTree(project, localRepository,
      artifactFactory, artifactMetadataSource, null, artifactCollector);
} catch (DependencyTreeBuilderException e) {
  throw new MojoExecutionException("Failed to create dependency tree.", e);
}
final CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
rootNode.accept(visitor);
final List<DependencyNode> nodes = visitor.getNodes();
```

What's the Maven 3 equivalent? Many involved classes have become deprecated in the meantime (`ArtifactCollector`, `ArtifactMetadataSource`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven 3 uses [Aether](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) for dependency resolution.  Near the bottom of the docs is another link to using Aether in Maven plugins.

Comment: Have to give credit (i.e. mark this as answer) for the pointer to Aether although I really like yegor256's lib jcabi-aether

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Aether](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) (this is what Maven 3 is using). I'd recommend to use a simple wrapper around it, called [jcabi-aether](http://aether.jcabi.com/) (I'm a developer of it).

Comment: Sorry but user944849 was faster pointing to Aether. Upvoted you, though.

Comment: jcabi-aether last release is from [2014](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aether/releases), is there any way better?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any working solution online, so I looked into the Maven source code and worked out a solution myself. Most of the following code was copied from maven source code, I have tested it with Maven 3.5.4 and it worked perfectly.

```java
import org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.ArtifactUtils;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.ResolutionScope;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultDependencyResolutionRequest;
import org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionResult;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectDependenciesResolver;
import org.eclipse.aether.graph.DependencyFilter;
import org.eclipse.aether.graph.DependencyNode;
import org.eclipse.aether.util.filter.AndDependencyFilter;
import org.eclipse.aether.util.filter.ScopeDependencyFilter;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.*;

@Mojo( name = "test-mojo", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME)
public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;
    @Inject
    private ProjectDependenciesResolver dependenciesResolver;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        try {
            Collection<String> scopesToResolve = new HashSet<>();
            scopesToResolve.add("compile");
            scopesToResolve.add("provided");
            scopesToResolve.add("runtime");
            scopesToResolve.add("system");
            scopesToResolve.add("test");
            Collection<String> scopesToCollect = new HashSet<>();
            scopesToCollect.add("compile");
            scopesToCollect.add("provided");
            scopesToCollect.add("runtime");
            scopesToCollect.add("system");
            scopesToCollect.add("test");
            Collection<Artifact> projectArtifacts = new HashSet<>();
            projectArtifacts.add(project.getArtifact());
            DependencyFilter collectionFilter = new ScopeDependencyFilter( null, negate( scopesToCollect ) );
            DependencyFilter resolutionFilter = new ScopeDependencyFilter( null, negate( scopesToResolve ) );
            resolutionFilter = AndDependencyFilter.newInstance( collectionFilter, resolutionFilter );
            resolutionFilter = AndDependencyFilter.newInstance( resolutionFilter, new ReactorDependencyFilter( projectArtifacts ) );
            DefaultDependencyResolutionRequest request =
                    new DefaultDependencyResolutionRequest( project, session.getRepositorySession() );
            request.setResolutionFilter( resolutionFilter );
            DependencyResolutionResult result = dependenciesResolver.resolve( request );

            // Here is your dependency gragh, you can do whatever you want with it.
            List<DependencyNode> children = result.getDependencyGraph().getChildren();
            List<DependencyNode> grandChildren = children.get(0).getChildren();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MojoExecutionException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Collection<String> negate( Collection<String> scopes )
    {
        Collection<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll( result, "system", "compile", "provided", "runtime", "test" );

        for ( String scope : scopes )
        {
            if ( "compile".equals( scope ) )
            {
                result.remove( "compile" );
                result.remove( "system" );
                result.remove( "provided" );
            }
            else if ( "runtime".equals( scope ) )
            {
                result.remove( "compile" );
                result.remove( "runtime" );
            }
            else if ( "compile+runtime".equals( scope ) )
            {
                result.remove( "compile" );
                result.remove( "system" );
                result.remove( "provided" );
                result.remove( "runtime" );
            }
            else if ( "runtime+system".equals( scope ) )
            {
                result.remove( "compile" );
                result.remove( "system" );
                result.remove( "runtime" );
            }
            else if ( "test".equals( scope ) )
            {
                result.clear();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    private static class ReactorDependencyFilter
            implements DependencyFilter
    {

        private Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();

        ReactorDependencyFilter( Collection<Artifact> artifacts )
        {
            for ( Artifact artifact : artifacts )
            {
                String key = ArtifactUtils.key( artifact );
                keys.add( key );
            }
        }

        public boolean accept(DependencyNode node, List<DependencyNode> parents )
        {
            org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency dependency = node.getDependency();
            if ( dependency != null )
            {
                org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact a = dependency.getArtifact();
                String key = ArtifactUtils.key( a.getGroupId(), a.getArtifactId(), a.getVersion() );
                return !keys.contains( key );
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Also, notice that you need to add some dependencies to make it work. Here is mine.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-common-artifact-filters</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```